# Microsoft.Office.Interop doesn't contain any public member or couldn't be found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp

Having a warning in my solution:-

> Warning   306 Namespace or type specified in the Imports
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop' doesn't contain any public member or cannot
>   be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains
>   at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name
>   doesn't use any aliases.

I added a reference to the `Microsoft 11.0 Object Library`, but the warning remains.

I note that when adding the reference, the path shown in the Add Reference dialogue was `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE11\MSL.DLL`, which exists, but in the Properies screen the path is given as `C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC\Office\11.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll`, which doesn't.

My Question: Is this the right thing to include? If it is, why does it not work? If not, what should I be using?

I suspect this problem is causing a number of the 300-odd compilation errors currently being reported.

This is Visual Basic 2010 Express running on Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You have to remove old reference of that file add new reference as when we are copying file from one machine to another machine the reference for assembly is some time also taking from copied machine.

so you can check this,

1. Select ->Properties of project
2. Go to the reference 3.check the reference of assembly exists or not
3. if path showing "The system cannot find the reference specified"
4. remove the reference and add the new reference